# Mysql - LEFT JOIN with COUNT

Tags: mysql

I have 2 database tables

1. directory
2. directory_category

They are linked by the category id (as cat_id & id) in both tables respectively

---

I want to list all the categories in **directory_category** and at the same time count how many records are found in **directory** for this category (using a single sql query)

I have tried

```
SELECT 
      directory_category.id
      directory_category.category_name
      directory.cat_id
      count(directory) as total_records
      FROM directory_category
      LEFT JOIN directory
      ON directory_category.id = directory.cat_id
```

This query only produces one record and the **total_records** seems to be the sum of the entire **directory** table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    directory_category.id,
    directory_category.category_name,
    directory.cat_id,
    COUNT(directory.id) AS total_records
FROM directory_category
LEFT JOIN directory ON directory_category.id = directory.cat_id
GROUP BY directory_category.id
```

Comment: total_records is coming up as 1, for all records

Answer (score 0):

At a guess (and a quick one), I'd say something like:

```
SELECT 
    directory_category.id,
    directory_category.category_name,
    directory.cat_id,
    count
FROM
    directory_category
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            count(directory) as total_records
        FROM
            directory
        INNER JOIN
            directory_category
        ON
            directory_category.id = directory.cat_id
    ) AS count
```

But you'd need to play around with it, obviously.